# Making a program to wait for Volley response

Tags: java, android, android-volley, synchronous

I'm loading a DB on app's startup and right after that I check whether there are any updates on the server.
I use Volley for that.
The problem is, the program starts the data updating before it even got the value from Response. 
So what I need is to wait for the response to finish and only then update my data with the jsonArray I got from there. But Volley is asynchronous so I can't figure out a way to do that and I'm not even sure that's something possible.
Can something like this be implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

Create an activity that act like a SplashScreen. The activity only shows to the user a loading screen and in the background is waiting for the volley request. When the request ends, the activity parse the data and do whatever you want. After that launch the second activity to show the data to the user.

Other alternative is just display a fullscreen progress dialog and dismiss the dialog when the request finish.

Comment: Thank you.
Though I think I would need another implementation.  I'll explain:
I already do have a splash activity. I have AsyncTask in it that loads the DB in the background. In that very same background I check updates with Volley. 
I've got like:
`Map<String,Password> passwordsToUpdate = VolleyClass.checkUpdates(contex);`
which basically just tells volley to check for updates but it doesn't wait for it. So - an empty just-created  passwordsToUpdate passes on to a method that is responsible for implementing these updates. 
What do you say if I solve this with a custom listener? (Callbacks)

Comment: Yes, looks good a callback. Only launch the next activity when de callback is fired.